# Difference between 'at first' and 'first'

Tags: phrase-meaning

As far as I understood from PEU we use *at first* to making a contrast with what happened erlier and later. In other cases we use just *first*. But I faced with the example

> at first Hugo tried to be patient

[there](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/first?searchDictCode=all)

*At first* was used although we didn't making a contrast. Couldn't you explain?

Comment: The definition for the example you mentioned does not say anything about "contrast".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael Swan indeed states in Unit 84 of his "Practical English Usage" that **at first** is often followed by **but**.

But *often* does not mean *always* and does not mean *in the same sentence*. A contrast might be provided in a following sentence or not provided expressly and remain an implication only.

> At first Hugo tried to be patient. It's easy to understand that with his fiery temperament this patience did not last.

Here, we use no **but** but a contrast is provided in a sequent sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*at first* is used in a normal way there.

*Something like...*

> At first, I tried to be calm and cool **but then** I lost my temper.

So, maybe, Hugo first tried to be patient in whatsoever situation he was in.

Answer (score 0):

The contrast is implied in sentences such as this one.  "At first Hugo tried to be patient" implies that later on he became impatient without actually stating it.  If you said "At first Hugo tried to be patient but later he remained patient" it would be grammatically correct but most native speakers would be scratching their heads wondering why it wasn't stated as "Huge was patient" in the first place.